# Loading an xlsx or csv file from Sharepoint into Spotfire using IronPython script

Tags: ironpython, spotfire, tibco

if I try to load the data using below script, the html code is being loaded instead of proper data. The given link leads to the direct source of xlsx or csv file (if you run that link in the browser, the xlsx or csv file will start downloading automatically). I would be glad to hear why this kind of situation happens and how to love this problem.

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Net')
from System.Net import HttpWebRequest, NetworkCredential
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Import import TextFileDataSource, TextDataReaderSettings

readerSettings = TextDataReaderSettings()
readerSettings.Separator = ";"
readerSettings.CultureName = "en-GB"

req = HttpWebRequest.Create("some link to xlsx file")

user_agent = 'individual user-agent'
req.UserAgent = user_agent
req.Method = "GET"

req.UseDefaultCredentials = True
#req.PreAuthenticate = True
user = Document.Properties["Username"]
password = Document.Properties["Password"]

req.Credentials = NetworkCredential(user, password)

rsp = req.GetResponse()
dSource = TextFileDataSource(rsp.GetResponseStream(),readerSettings)
rsp.Close()

dataManager = Document.Data
dataTable = dataManager.Tables[document.Name]
dataTable.ReplaceData(dSource)
```

Comment: what is the HTML that's being output? does it contain any message about what's happening?

Comment: Here are some images of the html code. The loaded file should has just 30 columns, but as seen on one of the images there is more than that (surely it is connected with that errors shown on the images). Here is a link to google drive: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jcANyeeMabeP1T28RwXZjU8-QClUTAU-?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

the important part of the HTML returned isn't "Javascript is disabled", it's "**We can't sign you in** because Javascript is disabled." based on this it sounds like your issue is that you haven't properly authenticated your session.

I would try to validate by loading this code into the Python IDE of your choice and try it independent of Spotfire.

the correct way to access Sharepoint, most likely, is through the Sharepoint API. I don't have experience with this but I'm sure some googling could turn up a solution. once you have a (third-party library free!) solution working in Python, you can adapt it to Spotfire without too much trouble.

Comment: I tried to login using .Net API as above in Visual Studio for IronPython project and the problem still occurs. I was googling for logging into SharePoint Online, but I didn't get any working solutions for my case. I was searching for Python default libraries with which I could connect to SharePoint 365, but I didn't find any solution ([link](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/tree/b849de85add5031048f4b2947287ca411c040069) using [link](https://community.tibco.com/questions/does-anyone-know-if-its-possible-add-additional-python-modules-spotfire)).

Comment: since we've eliminated Spotfire as the issue, you may want to ask this on the IronPython and/or Sharepoint topics in that case. unfortunately I'm not really familiar with Sharepoint and can't help you narrow down a better solution :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that worked for me. Instead of using **HttpWebRequest**, use **WebClient**. This has a function named '**DownloadFile**' which takes the url of the file and path where you want to save it in the Temp Folder -  this enables it to work on the *Web Browser* as well. (changing the download file path, might not work on the web server.)

Make sure you have created and added an app for Spotfire in Sharepoint and have the access tokens ready for authentication.

```
# Import libraries
import System
from System import *
from System.IO import *
from System.Net import *
from System.Security import *
from System.Text import *
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Import import *

# Temp folder path
localPath= Path.GetTempPath()

# Download Sharepoint Files to temp folder
client = WebClient()
client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_tokens)
client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f")

uri = Uri("https://<sharepoint_server>/sites/{sitename}/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/{sitename}/Shared%20Documents/{filename.xlsx}')/$value")
# Adjust your API according to you file path

client.DownloadFile(uri, localPath + filename)

# Import the files and Merge
listExcelFiles = Directory.GetFiles(localPath, "*.xlsx")
for file in listExcelFiles:
    dtCurr = collDt.Add(file.replace(".xlsx",""), Document.Data.CreateFileDataSource(file))
    dtCurr.ReplaceData(DataTableDataSource(dtCurr))

    # Delete the file in Temp after importing
    File.Delete(file)
```

More information about the API can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-6.0)